# Statistical approach to comparing deviations between two groups before and after a treatment

Tags: t-test, difference-in-difference

I have two groups - device X and Y - and measured a continuous variable (angle) before and after treatment. I would like to test which device showed a larger difference in angle after the treatment. My initial approach was to calculate the differences for angle before and after treatment (after - before angle) and compare the mean angle difference between both devices using an independent t-test. This demonstrated a higher angle difference for device Y. Is this the right approach?